# Google Workspace API, API call to create a user?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

We're using code similar to this for creating the user. However, we get a 400 Error when we call the API. What is the correct way to call the API?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Admin SDK Directory API.
    Prints the emails and names of the first 10 users in the domain.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().create(customer='customer_name_here').execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We tried to add other arguments to the list but that also didn't work. We tried to find the docs for the API but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an issue with how you are creating the user, who you are inserting.

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

CREDENTIALS = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\Workspace-Installed-TestEverything.json'

STORED_USER_TOKEN = 'createUserToken.json'


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Admin SDK Directory API.
    Prints the emails and names of the first 10 users in the domain.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(STORED_USER_TOKEN):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(STORED_USER_TOKEN, SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(STORED_USER_TOKEN, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)


    new_user  = {
        "name": {
            "givenName": "Contact",
            "familyName": "Daimto",
        },
        "primaryEmail": "xxx@daimto.com",
        "recoveryEmail": "xxxx@daimto.com",
        "password": "Temp42!!!",
        "changePasswordAtNextLogin": True
    }
    response = service.users().insert(body=new_user ).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```